# Vim-snippet with multiple references to a placeholder doesn't work

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a MATLAB `function` snippet for `vim-snipmate`. The snippet looks like this:

```
snippet fun                                                                 
   function [ ${1:returnVals} ] = ${2:name}( ${3:args} )                     
   % ${2:name}                                                      
   %   what does the function do?
   %   ${3:args}                                                     
   %                                                                         



 end
```

This works as in when I type `fun` and hit Tab the template gets generated.

However after I type in the return variables and hit Tab again, the second placeholder does not get marked for editing, but the Tab character is inserted in the `returnVals` field.

If I remove the comment placeholders the snippet works.

Is there any way to get the function name and the arguments and place them in the comments?

Comment: I think its because you have got two jump position for second and third placeholders. The mirrors should be `$2` and `$3`, not `${2:name}` and `${3:args}`

Comment: @dNitro Great, it works! If you write an answer that explains it I'll accept it. The one from romainl works but lacks any kind of explanation...

Comment: @Dr.Nefario see my edit.

Comment: @Dr.Nefario, romainl explanations are always great. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${n}` notation is used to define a tab stop *without* a placeholder.

The `${n:foo}` notation is used to define a tab stop *with* a placeholder.

The `$n` notation is used to mirror the value inserted at the corresponding tab stop.

In your snippet, you redefine the second and third tab stop with `${n:foo}` instead of mirroring them with `$n`.

Here is a fixed version of your snippet:

```
snippet fun                                                                 
    function [ ${1:returnVals} ] = ${2:name}( ${3:args} )                     
    % $2                                                      
    %   what does the function do?
    %   $3                                                     
    %
    ${4}
    end
```